# A particular inequality to whole solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, numerical-methods

Let $m$ and $n$ be two positive integers. Assume that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. What are the $(i,j)$ ordered pairs of non-negative integers that satisfy $$ (i+1)m+(j+1)n<mn$$

Do you know in the literature articles that deal with this type of inequalities to whole solutions?
Thank you, greetings.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint (which might be partly useful), consider the gcd $d$ of two integers $m,n>0$. Then by Bezout's theorem, $d = am + bn$ for some integers $a,b$.
Here we have $d\leq mn$ and $d=mn$ iff $m,n$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just edited the question, adding the assumption that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. I forgot to point this out, it is the case that interests me.